# Terraform and Azure: Unable to provision Storage Account

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to provision a storage account but running it results in error:

```
Error: Error reading static website for AzureRM Storage Account "sa12345461234512name":
accounts.Client#GetServiceProperties: 
Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: 
Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" 
Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\n
RequestId:05930d46-301e-00ac-6d72-f021f0000000\n
Time:2020-03-02T09:09:44.9417598Z"
```

Running OS Windows 10 Pro.

Steps to replicate (in Powershell with Azure CLI installed)

1. az login
2. mkdir dummyFolder
3. cd dummyFolder
4. create config.tf
5. terraform init
6. terraform plan
7. terraform apply -auto-approve

Config.tf contents

```
# Configure the Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.0.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "Australia East"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "sa12345461234512name"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Not sure what i am missing, all other resources work fine, just the storage account.

Comment: this looks like a lack of permissions? what are your permissions on the subscruption?

Comment: i've not applied any permissions to subscription, so whatever the default settings are is what i am using. It advises that i am admin on the subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Its got to do with Terraform.
Just checked for updates and notices 0.12.21 is out (I was runnning 0.12.20).

Seems like if running AzureARM 2.0.0 then really need to be min 0.12.21 to make it work.

Comment: This didn't work for me, whereas the answer proposed by Doug worked. Can you confirm if bumping up the patch version of terraform really fixed this issue?

Comment: @aquaraga yup when i had the issue the one that worked was simple bump up. The version i left as per question (still use that version for stuffing around)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the azure provider, see: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5869

Update your provider; it doesn't seem to be related to the terraform version.

From:

```
# Configure the Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  # whilst the `version` attribute is optional, we recommend pinning to a given version of the Provider
  version = "=2.0.0"
  features {}
}
```

To:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 2.1.0" 
  features {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this since none of above worked. In my case it first didn't work, then next day worked just to not work again in the evening... Not changing versions or anything, was same computer.

It turned out that my time settings on my Ubuntu running in Windows was skewed. Just simply running a `sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov` to update time solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as [@tesharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495089/9449426) experienced.
On my Ubuntu WSL2 the following command fixed the problem:

```
sudo hwclock -s
```